# How to get max value by specified key from Map in java

Tags: java, list, dictionary, data-structures, hashmap

I have list scores sentence from documents , and every max score will be inserted to each index. For example :

> Index 0 = 0.1
>
> Index 1 = 0.3
>
> Index 2 = 0.2
>
> Index 3 = 0.5
>
> Index 4 = 0.4
>
> Index 5 = 0.6

The index of list score will set to the `Map` as a `value` , and the `key` of list documents is :

> Doc 1
>
> Doc 2
>
> Doc 3

After I use looping with `Map<listDocuments, Index>` and I get the list such as

> Doc 1 = Index 0
>
> Doc 1 = Index 1
>
> Doc 1 = Index 2
>
> Doc 2 = Index 3
>
> Doc 2 = Index 4
>
> Doc 3 = Index 5

The problem is, i can't display document who have max value, and i only get the last `value` of each documents like this.

> Doc 1 = Index 2
>
> Doc 2 = Index 4
>
> Doc 3 = Index 5

While I want to display it according to max value such below.

> Doc 1 = Index 1 (0.3)
>
> Doc 2 = Index 3 (0.5)
>
> Doc 3 = Index 5 (0.6)

Here is my code

```
int index = 0;
int index2 = 0;
double max = 0.0;
double max2 = 0.0;

LinkedHashMap< List<Integer>, Integer> data = new LinkedHashMap< List<Integer>, Integer>();

 for (int d1 = 0; d1 < d - 1; d1++) {
     for (int d2 = d1 + 1; d2 < d; d2++) {

          //...Other code.....

     }

     listSentence.add(ste.maxScore());
     listSentence2.add(ste.maxScore2());

     max = Collections.max(listSentence);
     max2 = Collections.max(listSentence2);

     index = listSentence.indexOf(max);
     index2 = listSentence.indexOf(max2);

     data.put(d1, index);
     data.put(d2, index2);
}

//code for displaying it

for (Map.Entry list : data.entrySet()) {
      System.out.println("" + stemmings
                    .get(list.getKey().hashCode())
                    .get(list.getValue().hashCode()));
}
```

Any answer will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you use ur document as Key ofc there will only be one Index for each document. The Key can only be present once.

Comment: yes i think like that, but i dont know to use it according to what i want as display above

Comment: I'd suggest using your document as `Key` and either a `List` or a `Set`of your indexes as `Value`. At the end you iterate over the `Collection` used as `Value` and remember the index with the greatest score.

Comment: Or you check whether an index is already present as `Value` and overwrite it if the new index has a greater score

Comment: can you give some code for example ? or modify my code in above . .thanks before

Comment: I don't completly understand your code above. `d2` is not declared when you use `data.put(d2, index2)` and is also not  a `List<Integer>`. So the above example won't even compile

Comment: or you have an example code for me according to you said before ? so i have more undersatnd about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so a simple example:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> data = new HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>>();
for(;;) // use your loop here
{
    int document;
    int index;
    // Do some stuff to get index and so on
    if(!data.containsKey(document))
    {
        data.put(document, new HashSet<Integer>());
    }
    data.get(document).add(index);
}

// Output

for(Map.Entry<Integer, Set<Integer>> entry : data.entrySet())
{
    int maxIndex = -1;
    int maxScore = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(Integer index : entry.getValue())
    {
        int score;
        //get the score for index
        if(score > maxScore)
        {
            maxScore = score;
            maxIndex = index;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Document: "+entry.getKey()+" Index with max score: "+maxIndex);
}
```

Comment: Okey thanks. I'll try that code and back again soon. .

Comment: Thanks !! . it works after i've tried with each modify with my code . .